# html fixed width table to match textarea

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a textarea box with a set number of rows/cols to give it a set size. Under that textbox I'm trying to add a table with the same dimensions, I can change the width by setting style='width:240%' but when I resize the window the table resizes too, how can I set the table to have a fixed width and not resize dynamically? I tried doing so with:

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100px;
}
```

in the html but no luck

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/b4z735tk/18/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 68%!important;
}
```